# How to loop text file each line and append other text wrap each line

Tags: bash, shell

How to loop text file each line and append other text wrap each line in shell

text.txt

```
a
b
c
```

script

```
while read p; do
  echo $p
done </Users/admin/Desktop/tutorial/text.txt
```

result

```
<url>
  <loc>http://domain/a</loc>
  <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://domain/b</loc>
  <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://domain/c</loc>
  <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` is your friend:

```
while read p; do
printf "<url>\n\t<loc>http://domain/%s</loc>\n\t<priority>0.9</priority>\n</url>\n" "$p"
done < /Users/admin/Desktop/tutorial/text.txt

<url>
   <loc>http://domain/a</loc>
   <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://domain/b</loc>
   <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://domain/c</loc>
   <priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
```